# Access a method of a controller across multiple views

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, methods, partial-views

Whats the best methodology for accessing a method of a controller across multiple views?  Let me explain, I have a partial view that contains a "Video tutorial" button that appears on every page of my application.  When pressed it accesses the method of a controller using ajax to parse the database and display the corresponding video for the view you are in.  There are a number of pages that will be the exact same video and I'd rather not duplicate my method across all those controllers, I want to write the method once for those particular views and then call that method from each view.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a Base controller that has 1 method on it and doesn't return a view so I added my methods to that controller and then added my ajax call for the method to a partial view (a navigation that appears on all the pages that show this video).  This works perfectly.  Hope this helps someone else.